# Getting a random stack overflow when calling .SubmitChanges() linq

Tags: c#, linq, stack-overflow

I get a stackoverflow exception when calling  `{DataContext}.SubmitChanges()`... I wish I knew which lines of code to post to help clarify the situation but the exception does not give any information when thrown it says:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

and then in View Detail I get:

```
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
```

I have looked through all of my properties in this view model to make sure that everything is declared correctly and that there are no issues causing the stackoverflow exception there...It only occurs after when `SubmitChanges()` is called.

Here is code where the submit gets called:

```
public void VerifyAdvancePaymentsAndSave()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!VerifyTakeHomeActualBreakDownForAdvancePayments())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        "Cash, Check, and Money Order fields must add up to the amount in the Take Home Actual field!",
                        "Validation Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

                    return;
                }

                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save this payment?", "Save", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    return;

                if (!UserController.CreateUserController().CheckAccess(UserController.RestrictedAccessAction.EditCollections))
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (InitialCollectionAction == CollectionAction.ViewAdvancePayment)
                {
                    foreach (Advance a in Advances)
                    {
                        foreach (AdvancePayment ap in a.AdvancePayments)
                        {
                            AdvancePayment newAP = sp.AdvancePayments.Where(adv => adv.Id == ap.Id).SingleOrDefault();

                            if (newAP != null)
                            {
                                newAP.Payment = ap.Payment;
                                newAP.IsSaved = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Could not find Advance Payment to apply amount to!");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        CurrentCollection.Status = BatchStatus.Open.ToString();
                        CurrentCollection.CollectionDate = DateTime.Now;
                        CurrentCollection.IsAdvancedPayment = true;
                        CurrentCollection.CollectionMachines = null;


                        //sp.Collections.InsertOnSubmit(CurrentCollection);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error inserting changes!");
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    sp.SubmitChanges();

                    if (InitialCollectionAction == CollectionAction.ViewAdvancePayment)
                        MessageBox.Show("Advance Payment was saved Successfully!");
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Advance Payment was submitted Sucessfully!");

                    CloseTab();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error submitting changes!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = UserController.CreateUserController().LoggedInUser.UserName + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace;
                EmailController.CreateEmailController().SendEmail("URM Error", message);
            }
        }
```

Stack trace - before the SubmitChanges() call

```
   at URM.ViewModels.CollectionsViewModel.VerifyAdvancePaymentsAndSave()
   at URM.Commands.CollectionsSaveCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at URM.App.Main()
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Models used in this view model:

```
public class AdvancePaymentsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int AdvanceId { get; set; }
        public string PaymentId { get; set; }
        public decimal Payment { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }

        private string _status;
        public string Status
        {
            get
            {
                return _status;
            }

            set
            {
                _status = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Status");
            }
        }

        private Brush _brushObj;
        public Brush BrushObj
        {
            get
            {
                return _brushObj;
            }

            set
            {
                _brushObj = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BrushObj");
            }
        }

        private AdvancePayment _advancePayment;
        public AdvancePayment AdvancePayment
        {
            get
            {
                return _advancePayment;
            }

            set
            {
                _advancePayment = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AdvancePayment");
            }
        }

        private Visibility _voidButtonVisibility;
        public Visibility VoidButtonVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return _voidButtonVisibility;
            }

            set
            {
                _voidButtonVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("VoidButtonVisibility");
            }
        }
}

public class AdvancePaymentsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int AdvanceId { get; set; }
        public string PaymentId { get; set; }
        public decimal Payment { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }

        private string _status;
        public string Status
        {
            get
            {
                return _status;
            }

            set
            {
                _status = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Status");
            }
        }

        private Brush _brushObj;
        public Brush BrushObj
        {
            get
            {
                return _brushObj;
            }

            set
            {
                _brushObj = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BrushObj");
            }
        }

        private AdvancePayment _advancePayment;
        public AdvancePayment AdvancePayment
        {
            get
            {
                return _advancePayment;
            }

            set
            {
                _advancePayment = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AdvancePayment");
            }
        }

        private Visibility _voidButtonVisibility;
        public Visibility VoidButtonVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return _voidButtonVisibility;
            }

            set
            {
                _voidButtonVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("VoidButtonVisibility");
            }
        }
     }
}
```

After enabling debugging .Net Framework source code... I see the stackoverflow exception gets thrown in the dispatcher class

```
 private void PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame) 
        {
            SynchronizationContext oldSyncContext = null;
            SynchronizationContext newSyncContext = null;
            MSG msg = new MSG(); 

            _frameDepth++; 
            try 
            {
                // Change the CLR SynchronizationContext to be compatable with our Dispatcher. 
                oldSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
                newSyncContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(this);
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(newSyncContext);

                try
                { 
                    while(frame.Continue) 
                    {
                        if (!GetMessage(ref msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0)) 
                            break;

                        TranslateAndDispatchMessage(ref msg); //*<--------- gets thrown here*
                    } 

                    // If this was the last frame to exit after a quit, we 
                    // can now dispose the dispatcher. 
                    if(_frameDepth == 1)
                    { 
                        if(_hasShutdownStarted)
                        {
                            ShutdownImpl();
                        } 
                    }
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    // Restore the old SynchronizationContext. 
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(oldSyncContext);
                }
            }
            finally 
            {
                _frameDepth--; 
                if(_frameDepth == 0) 
                {
                    // We have exited all frames. 
                    _exitAllFrames = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

After crashing in the dispatcher here is the stack trace:

```
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) Line 2281 + 0x35 bytes    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) Line 368 + 0x9 bytes  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() Line 327 + 0x34 bytes Unknown
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) Line 2745 C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) Line 1841    C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window) Line 261 + 0x9 bytes C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() Line 222 + 0x15 bytes    C#
    URM.exe!URM.App.Main() + 0x59 bytes C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x6b bytes    
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x27 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x6f bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x41 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

So after taking the advice of @KellyGendron and @David I ended up getting the stackoverflow exception to be thrown in the ChangeTracker class

```
 internal override bool IsMemberPendingGeneration(MetaDataMember keyMember) {
                    if (this.IsNew && keyMember.IsDbGenerated) { 
                        return true;
                    }
                    // look for any FK association that has this key member (should only be one)
                    foreach (MetaAssociation assoc in type.Associations) { 
                        if (assoc.IsForeignKey) {
     /*CRASHES HERE*/      int index = assoc.ThisKey.IndexOf(keyMember); 
                            if (index > -1) { 
                                // we must have a reference to this other object to know if its side of
                                // the association is generated or not 
                                object otherItem = null;
                                if (assoc.ThisMember.IsDeferred) {
                                    otherItem = assoc.ThisMember.DeferredValueAccessor.GetBoxedValue(this.current);
                                } 
                                else {
                                    otherItem = assoc.ThisMember.StorageAccessor.GetBoxedValue(this.current); 
                                } 
                                if (otherItem != null) {
                                    if (assoc.IsMany) { 
                                        // Can't be pending generation for a value that would have to be the same
                                        // across many rows.
                                        continue;
                                    } 
                                    else {
                                        StandardTrackedObject trackedOther = (StandardTrackedObject)this.tracker.GetTrackedObject(otherItem); 
                                        if (trackedOther != null) { 
                                            MetaDataMember otherMember = assoc.OtherKey[index];
                                            return trackedOther.IsMemberPendingGeneration(otherMember); 
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    } 
                    return false; 
                }
            } 
        }
```

The keymember seems to be from what I can make out of its partially available attributes is the Location class (database table) and it seems to be stuck on the ID Column

Comment: Please show some code so that we can help.

Comment: Get a stack trace to observe the cycle.

Comment: I posted code of when the submit gets called...for my tests the application goes into the else statement

Comment: @usr the stacktrace is not available after the call

Comment: @jharr100 what do you mean "after the call"? Set the debugger to break on all exceptions and look at the call stack window.

Comment: Just a guess (hence using comment not answer) but do you have a recursive data structure that somehow isnt detected in serialization?

Comment: @usr I have the stack trace prior to the SubmitChanges() method call - posting now

Comment: @ChrisBallard I looked for that and outside of the models I created I am only using classes created by Linq

Comment: @jharr100: can you show your models with their fields and constructors?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel added them

Comment: To debug the SubmitChanges() call you should turn on Tools -> Options -> Debugging ->  Enable .NET Framework (See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)

Comment: Where is the sp variable initialized?

Comment: @caspian it is initalized in the constructor of the viewmodel

Comment: @David downloading public symbols now - will let you know what I find

Comment: So after taking @David's suggestion I have more information...it seems to be crashing in the dispatcher class

Comment: Is the line being called sp.Collections.InsertOnSubmit(CurrentCollection)? Or is it commented out when you get your exception?

Comment: @caspian it happens either way

Comment: You have to get the stack trace to see the cycle. All this guessing is not necessary! Just look at the exception.stacktrace. Not before the crash, or after. Just at the exact moment the stack is overflown.

Comment: @usr A stackoverflow can not show a stacktrace.

Comment: @David why can't it? I have seen it myself in the Call Stack window. Are you saying it is missing in the exception details? Even if that is the case, the debugger *will* show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much to do - it ended up being an issue where one of my tables had a foreign key to its own primary key. This caused the circular reference to occur. The best way I found to debug this was the enable debugging of .NET source code and then I had to place a break point in the OnPropertyChanged method in my ViewModel. At that point, I was able to get the exception to occur in the ChangeaTracker class otherwise it would break in the Dispatcher class...

Comment: Great! It always kills me when there is no answer to these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I could be reading your code incorrectly, however in this snippet it looks like newAP.Payment would be pointing to itself which may be what is confusing the serializer so badly. Again forgive me if I'm misreading, very sleep deprived today.

```
foreach (AdvancePayment ap in a.AdvancePayments)
    {
        AdvancePayment newAP = sp.AdvancePayments
            .Where(adv => adv.Id == ap.Id).SingleOrDefault();
        if (newAP != null)
        {
            newAP.Payment = ap.Payment;
            ...
```

If that isn't the case you may want to try breaking the save into multiple parts, for example setting the association to null and then specifying by ID. There is a similar case here that may help...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/d4438aaa-a916-4335-b182-ded75f162c2d/datacontextsubmitchanges-throws-stack-overflow-exception-on-rather-simple-insert

Comment: This code does not get called...it goes into the else statement where this is crashing

Comment: Are you sure it isn't getting pointed to itself in a previous iteration? You may want to also try adding a sp.SubmitChanges() after each db change in the method. Don't leave them in there obviously, but may help you to see exactly what portion of the query is making it choke.

Comment: I don't think I placed a breakpoint here and this code never gets called...Maybe I should post the code where the advance payment gets saved

Comment: Just speculating here as my MVVM is a little rusty, sounds like this is happening in the UI code not in the entities code at all. I'm wondering if maybe the INotifyProperyChanged dispatching isn't playing nice with the potentially circular reference on the object.

Comment: How would I be able to see if this is the issue?

Comment: Well I'm admittedly a bit out of my depth here as I'm a few years out of working with WPF. My suggestion would be to perhaps wire an event to the OnPropertyChanged event that writes to the debug window... theoretically it should be smart enough to handle cycles but who knows. I'd also look for any potentially circular dependencies in the UI and possibly post a little more about what is happening in your display code.

Comment: @jharr100 Maybe you can comment out OnPropertyChanged. This should show if it's the update or not. BTW your AdvancePaymentsModel class copied twice

Comment: Or just set a breakpoint and see if it keeps coming back there.

Comment: After putting a breakpoint there...everything seemed to be working ok but I ended up getting an exception in linq's ChangeTracker class...will add more detail to question

Comment: These plot twists are killing me :D

Comment: My advice would be to try and break this down more so we can see exactly where things are going wrong. For example there is code we aren't seeing like your actual control setup and your mapping code between entities and your view models. I'd extract the code as best you can, for example take the data modified by VerifyAdvancePaymentsAndSave and display to a console window to make sure we can enumerate over it. I think there are too many moving pieces here and it may be obfuscating the actual problem. If we can localize it to your query, the ui, or the vm Mapping it may make things more clear.

Comment: ahhhh...i dont know how but somehow the location table in the database ended up having a foreign key to its own primary key...this seems like a very silly discovery...Is it allowed to mark your answer as the correct answer - as this (and David's help) lead me to find the issue?

Comment: Really glad you found it - that was a really tricky, and interesting bug - thanks for keeping us posted! No idea on how close this was for an answer - conflict of interest and all that ;)

Comment: @jharr100: I suggest you add a new answer of your own where you explain the problem and mark it "community wiki". Afterwards: accept your own answer and upvote this one. That way people won't get confused when they have the same problem.